# How to receive a response from AWS S3 triggered lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-sdk-js

I currently have a setup where my mobile front-end performs an AWS s3 upload of an image. The s3 upload triggers a AWS lambda function that starts a AWS step-function (state-machine) which performs various jobs and actions.

I am looking for the best (and most time-efficient) way to get the output at the end of the step-function back to the mobile devise.

One way is to monitor the `executionARN` of the state machine and, when it is completed, fetch the data. This seems to be the case with awslabs lambda-refarch-imagerecognition implementation [here](https://github.com/awslabs/lambda-refarch-imagerecognition). However, my front-end is on mobile and I would rather not have to send and receive many request to check if the state-machine is finished.

Another possible solution is to refactor the process so that the s3 upload is a stand-alone event and, once it has been successful, make an API request to an AWS API-gateway that triggers the step-function. The API POST request will then return the response. The problem here is that the app must wait for the s3 response to proceed with starting the state-machine.

Is there a a better way to perform this sequence and receive a response. Ideally, the s3 upload would return the full response from the state-machine. This way there one request (image-upload) and one response.

Comment: You can try set a callback url that your front-end will listen to, and once the lambda finishes send the response to the callback url and let the mobile device know that it finished.

Comment: Have you looked at Amazon SNS Mobile Push Notifications?

Comment: @robsalzwedel Hi, would you mind sharing what you end up doing? thanks

Comment: @jarmod what if this is on a browser?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Amazon SNS -> push notifications.  You say you want to avoid making "many requests" (and waiting for responses - or polling).

Amazon SNS allows you to publish to a specific topic.

Anything which is "subscribed" to the topic, will (receive a notification / message), whenever one (a stateless update) is published to the topic.

[image: AWS SNS]

The "mobile front-end" (device - you mention) "would receive the message" / receive push notifications from the SNS endpoint / topic.

This could be triggered when the "state machine" completes, allowing the mobile device to "get a timely update" via a push notification.

This would avoid polling for a response.

Comment: How does SNS selectively send notifications / message to all subscribers? I noticed there is an attribute filtering, do I filter for a specific user's id / email and only send the notification to ONE user?

Comment: I found out from this thread it is actually possible to have one topic per user.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254516/aws-sns-workaround-for-100-000-topics-limit
Thus, we don't have to filter the messages based on users' IDs or emails.