# SNS FilterPolicy Limit increase

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

According to AWS documentation on [SNS limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_sns), you can only have 100 message filter policies per account per region.

I can ask for an increase to this, but I can't find any information on the web about what the costs or upper limits would be for increasing the filter policy count, similar to the question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254516/aws-sns-workaround-for-100-000-topics-limit?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) on topic count limits.

If I'm hoping to increase this limit by A LOT, what should I expect in terms of pricing or if it'll even be allowed?

I plan to ask for the increase, but was disappointed in not finding any available info on the web from others. I also would have posted this question in their forums, but I don't like their interface as much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heard back from AWS support and got a limit increase, but not as high as I'd like to fit my use case.

It seems as if you should use filter policies very judicially.